# Can alternatedocroot property be defined in Payara/GlassFish server?

Tags: jsf, glassfish, payara

I am using Payara Server, Community Edition, and wish to define an alternatedocroot property so as to serve a web page defined outside my application. I can make this work by adding a property to glassfish-web.xml, such as:

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/tutorials/* dir=C:\srv\ExtSTAR"/>
```

However, I'm running into an issue because while my application is developed under Windows, it is deployed to Linux, so I need a different path for the value of the "dir" attribute depending on whether I'm trying to run the application in my development environment or build it for deployment. My hope is that instead of defining the property in my application, I could instead add it to the server configuration. However, while I did see a hint somewhere that that could be done, I have been unable to make it happen. Is this possible to do, and if not, is there any alternative strategy available that would let me accommodate both my development and deployment environments without having to remember to change the configuration when that's necessary?

EDIT: There is actually documentation [here](https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2020.7/documentation/payara-server/server-configuration/http/virtual-servers.html) that indicates this can be done, but I am still unable to make it work this way.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question on the accident of having to rebuild my environment due to a disk crash. Under Linux, I use the following definition for the `alternatedocroot_1` property:

```
  <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/tutorials/* dir=/srv/ExtSTAR"/>
```

Upon trying to run the application under Windows, that would fail because that directory cannot be found. The error in server.log told me it was looking for the `/srv/ExtSTAR` directory within the domain directory. So all I needed to do was create that directory structure within the domain directory and voila, no errors when I run in my development environment.